# Android application config parameters and gps

Tags: android, gps

I have two major problem concerning geolocation in android.

1. Concerning config parameters: I mean those informations we use to enter once when installing the application and use each time (login credentials for example).

**How can i achieve this ? Any good tutorial will be the welcome.**

2. Concerning gps, how can I determine programmatically that I've reached a certain point (my destination)?

I have the GPS coordinates of my destination and want to determine programmatically that I'm at my destination, using my own coordinates.

Comment: You can use [SharedPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example) to persist the config params.

Comment: Use [GeoFencing](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) to know  user's proximity to locations

Answer (score 0):

Check out the comments above. 
For example on GeoFencing, you can go through this detailed application:
[Google Samples on GeoFencing](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Geofencing)